# .net core 5 docker following example not running

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-5

I followed the instructions I have found online and this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app --no-restore

# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["my-app"]
```

I also have a .dockerignore because I was getting dir length exceeded errors:

```
Dockerfile
[b|B]in
[O|o]bj
```

When I try and run it I get this error stating that aspnetcore was not found:

```
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.AspNetCore.App&framework_version=5.0.0&arch=x64&rid=debian.10-x64
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: You should use `aspnet:5.0` instead of  `runtime:5.0` at the last step

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except answer mentioned by @mtkachenko with incorrect entrypoint, you have aspnet app thus you need aspnet librariers. Instead of runtime image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0` use `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually entry point looks like `ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my-app.dll"]`, not just `ENTRYPOINT ["my-app"]`.

Comment: I changed it as you mentioned and got a different error now: ```Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You intended to execute a .NET program:
      The application 'my-app' does not exist.
  * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
      It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
      Install a .NET SDK from:
        https://aka.ms/dotnet-download```

Comment: Usually it is 'my-app.dll' <- with .dll extension. Is it different in .net 5.0?

Comment: When I add the .dll I go back to the first error being reported.

Comment: Oh, ok. You have aspnet app. Instead of runtime image use ``mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0``. I think this should resolve problem.

Comment: Make this a rull answer please so I can give you a checkmark for future people.

Answer (score 0):

Updating dockerfile to use `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` instead of `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:5.0` resolved the issue for me.